# Android Soft keyboard

Tags: android

Android Soft keyboard is not automatically switching to **Alphabet mode** from **numeric mode** during navigating to other text box, why?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="select ur appropriate mode"
```

for your particular textbox

example ,shown below

```
  <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="text"=========returns text keyboard
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="number"=======returns numeric keyboard
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: its basically a web app in html not the android native, so only by using some html tags this should be achieved, i goggled i couldn't find any relevant solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `inputType` property to indicate what type of keyboard you want.

For example, say you have 2 edit boxes:

```
//alphabet keyboard is shown when user focus is on this box

<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

//numeric keyboard is shown when user focus is on this box   

<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```